# How to fetch the PDF file from device to be able to upload it from my application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm working on an application, Where it has a feature that allows users to upload(& downloading the uploaded ones) the images from gallery to server. Now I should be able to upload the PDF files from the device as well. How can I fetch the PDF files from iCloud? No clue on how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIDocumentPicker is the solution what I'm looking for
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

First, PDF files are accessible from apps documents or library. You have to check apps document directory and fetch the pdf files. Apart from these If you want to save the PDF file you have to download it and save in apps documents directory.

Comment: I mean files from device not from my app directories, want to get the pdf files from icloud drive

Comment: So you have to search for this feature and I hope it will be possible.. Check whatsapp for ios, attachment icon.

Comment: yes, wanted to implement the same way how whatsapp does

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the PDF files or any document unless until it is in your app's Sandbox. You can access user's gallery and upload images to the server.

If the file is in your Documents directory(sandbox) you can proceed with the following code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Append your file path to this documentsDirectory string and fetch it.

In case if your pdf file is in your app's bundle,

```
NSString *pdfFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfFileName" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how could whatsapp doing then,they are leting the users browse from icloud