# Swift - how to access all pdf files on device

Tags: ios, swift, file, pdf

I am trying to build an app that will allow users to see all pdf files that are on the device (in some kind of a list with a preview) [Regardless of which app it belongs to on the device, all should be shown]. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Not possible. Your app has no access to the sandbox of other apps. The best you can do is to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Comment: This topic should be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch the PDF file from device to be able to upload it from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786158/how-to-fetch-the-pdf-file-from-device-to-be-able-to-upload-it-from-my-applicatio)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but this is not possible on an iOS device because of a feature called sandboxing. Apple does not allow an app to access the sandbox of another app. Each app sits inside a sandbox of its own. This is iOS's security feature. There is no way to go around this feature.

Reference - [About App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html)